# getimagesize() not working properly in Yii2

Tags: php, yii2, getimagesize

Cannot get this function to work inside my controller. It always return

```
getimagesize(/web/uploads/image1.jpg): failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

calling it like this:

```
$user->avatar = Yii::$app->getUrlManager()->getBaseUrl() . '/uploads/' . $model->avatar->baseName . '.' . $model->avatar->extension;   
getimagesize($user->avatar );
```

Any solutions?

Accessing /web/uploads/image1.jpg from browser image is shown.

Comment: getimagesize is Php function its should work . Have you try with full path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getimagesize` is native PHP function and has nothing to do with framework. You need to specify full image path using `basePath`, not `baseUrl`. `baseUrl` is for displaying images.

Construct your path like this instead:

```
use Yii;

...

$imagePath = Yii::$app->basePath . '/web/uploads/' . $model->avatar->baseName . '.' . $model->avatar->extension;
```

You can also set the alias for `uploads` folder like this in `bootstrap.php` file (this example is for advanced app):

```
Yii::setAlias('uploads', dirname(dirname(__DIR__)) . '/frontend/web/uploads');
```

Then to get full path to `uploads` folder you can refer to it like this:

```
Yii::getAlias('uploads');
```